# Does gcc(windows + MinGW) defines SCNd8, SCNu8 in inttypes.h?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, c99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int8_t int8;
    int16_t int16;
    int32_t int32;
    int64_t int64;

    uint8_t uint8;
    uint16_t uint16;
    uint32_t uint32;
    uint64_t uint64;

    scanf("%"SCNd8"%"SCNd16"%"SCNd32"%"SCNd64"%"SCNu8"%"SCNu16"%"SCNu32"%"SCNu64, 
            &int8, &int16, &int32, &int64, &uint8, &uint16, &uint32, &uint64);

    printf("%"PRId8"\n%"PRId16"\n%"PRId32"\n%"PRId64"\n%"PRIu8"\n%"PRIu16"\n%"PRIu32"\n%"PRIu64"\n",
            int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64);

    return 0;
}
```

I can't compile this code using latest gcc + MinGW + Netbeans + Windows. Netbeans says "unable to resolve identifier SCNd8 and SCNu8". I can't find any reference for SCNd8 and SCNu8 on gcc man page although http://linux.die.net/include/inttypes.h defines them. I don't receive syntax error for using PRId8 or PRIu8.

MinGW inttypes.h (lacks SCNd8 and SCNu8 ) (sample code)

```
#define PRIXFAST64 "I64X"

#define PRIXMAX "I64X"
#define PRIXPTR "X"

/*
 *   fscanf macros for signed int types
 *   NOTE: if 32-bit int is used for int_fast8_t and int_fast16_t
 *   (see stdint.h, 7.18.1.3), FAST8 and FAST16 should have
 *   no length identifiers
 */

#define SCNd16 "hd"
#define SCNd32 "d"
#define SCNd64 "I64d"

#define SCNdLEAST16 "hd"
#define SCNdLEAST32 "d"
#define SCNdLEAST64 "I64d"

#define SCNdFAST16 "hd"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the following after `#include <inttypes.h>`:

```
#ifndef SCNd8
  #define SCNd8 "hhd"
#endif
#ifndef SCNu8
  #define SCNu8 "hhu"
#endif
```

Which should be appropriate for most platforms.

Clarification:
Where "most platforms" refers to platforms with a C99-compliant `fscanf`/`scanf` that can handle the `hh` prefix for `char`, not just the `h` prefix for `short`.

Comment: @bossgameboy: What version of gcc/mingw are you using?  the "hhd" and "hhu" formats don't work for me with 4.5.1 (even though they're already in `inttypes.h`).

Comment: @Michael: the "hh" prefix is part of C99 (not C90).  Check the man page for your version of scanf (or fscanf) to make sure it's compatible with "hh" for `char`.  (C90 just has "h" for `short`).

Comment: understood. But the question was specifically about MinGW, and the problem with using this on MinGW is that the compiler supports C99, but the core runtime library used by MinGW is Microsoft's `msvcrt.dll`, which doesn't.  So you can update MinGW to a version that supports `SCNd8` and friends in the `inttypes.h` header (or you you can patch the one you have, as suggested in the answer), but that does nothing to get support in the `scanf()` function itself.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting - I have MinGW with GCC Version 4.5.1 installed.

The format specifier macros in `inttypes.h` work for the most part, except for the the ones for inputting 8-bit ints (`SCNd8` and `SCNu8`). Those macros are defined in `inttypes.h`, but trying to use them doesn't work so well. With the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    int8_t int8 = 0;
    uint8_t uint8 = 0;

    scanf("%"SCNd8, &int8);
    scanf("%"SCNu8, &uint8);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following warnings:

```
C:\temp\test.c: In function 'main':
C:\temp\test.c:9:5: warning: unknown conversion type character 'h' in format
C:\temp\test.c:9:5: warning: too many arguments for format
C:\temp\test.c:10:5: warning: unknown conversion type character 'h' in format
C:\temp\test.c:10:5: warning: too many arguments for format
```

So it seems that GCC 4.5.1 and/or glibc don't support the "%hhd" and "%hhu" C99 format specifiers. If I run this program under a debugger, more than just the byte variables *do* end up being modified by the `scanf()` calls.

Just for reference, I'm using the following command to compile:

```
 "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc" -std=c99 -Wall -g  -Ic:\MinGW\include -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500 "C:\temp\test.c"  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -ladvapi32 -lshlwapi -loleaut32 -o "test".exe
```

Note that the various character-sized int input formats (that use "hh") in `inttypes.h` only get compiled in if the C99 standard is specified - they're protected by:

```
#if defined (__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
```

The other format specifiers are compiled in even for C90 compiles.

So you won't get the "hh" formats unless you use the `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` options (but remember that they don't seem to work anyway).

---

Update:

Of course!  The reason the "hhd" and "hhu' specifiers aren't supported is because the MinGW runtime uses the `scanf()` from Microsoft's `msvcrt.dll` which doesn't know anything about the new stuff in C99's input formats.  If you want to use these input formats, you'll need to use some other `scanf()` implementation.

As mentioned in MinGW's `inttypes.h`:

> MS runtime  scanf appears to treat "hh" as "h"

Comment: interesting, I am using MinGW 5.1.6 ( don't know what gcc version ), I looked at include folder of MinGW and searched for inttypes.h header and there are no definitions for SCNd8 or SCNu8.... here is the sample from MinGW inttypes.h

Comment: #define PRIXFAST64 "I64X"

#define PRIXMAX "I64X"
#define PRIXPTR "X"

/*
 *   fscanf macros for signed int types
 *   NOTE: if 32-bit int is used for int_fast8_t and int_fast16_t
 *   (see stdint.h, 7.18.1.3), FAST8 and FAST16 should have
 *   no length identifiers
 */

#define SCNd16 "hd"
#define SCNd32 "d"
#define SCNd64 "I64d"

#define SCNdLEAST16 "hd"
#define SCNdLEAST32 "d"
#define SCNdLEAST64 "I64d"

#define SCNdFAST16 "hd"

Comment: @bossgameboy: I'm using a MinGW package that's not from mingw.org (it's from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).  The versions of essential components are: gcc: 4.5.1, mingw-runtime: 3.18, w32api: 3.14.  I don't know what "MinGW 5.1.6" refers to exactly - where does that number come from?

Comment: don't know it just writes on mingw setup.exe look:http://img839.imageshack.us/i/capturejw.jpg/

Comment: @bossgameboy: I see.  It looks like that's not available from the MinGW SourceForge downloads anymore; apparently they've moved to a different installer.  If I'm not mistaken, the old installer had GCC 3.4.5 included in the package (you can run "`gcc --version`" to verify that). Installing a newer MinGW version should get you a `inttypes.h` with `SCNd8` and `SCNu8`, but as I noted there appear to be compiler/library problems with those input formats (I expect those problems also exist in older compiler versions).

Comment: I installed MinGW few weeks ago so I tought I have latest version, but truth is that I used direct links from this page http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/cpp-setup-instructions.html which is obsolete... Now I'm dowloading latest packages. thx for help

Comment: @bossgameboy: I just realized why these format specifiers don't work.  Updating your MinGW installation will get you the macros in `inttypes.h`, but since the `scanf()` being called is from `msvcrt.dll` there's no support for them in the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MinGW-w64, then according to the [MinGW-w64 FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gnu%20printf/), use the following define before includes

```
#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1
```

That means to use MinGW-w64's own `stdio.h` implementation, instead of deferring to Microsoft's one which does not support `SCNu8`.  This is a good idea anyway as the Microsoft implementation has various other major bugs.

There are two entries in the FAQ concerning the problem, here's [the link to the other one](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/printf%20and%20scanf%20family/).

---

I tested this using using `gcc (x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.1.0` with the following code

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  uint_fast8_t i = 0;
  scanf("%" SCNuFAST8 "\n", &i);
  printf("%" PRIuFAST8 "\n", i);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Without the `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`, I got

```
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:7:9: error: unknown conversion type character 'h' in format [-Werror=format=]
   scanf("%" SCNuFAST8 "\n", &i);
         ^
a.c:7:9: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
```

I'm compiling my code like this

```
>gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror a.c
```

Answer (score 1):

The SCN macros are in the C99 standard, so something is going wrong. Perhaps you'd have to compile with `-std=c99`.

Comment: I have no problem using any other c99 feature accept printing long double value ( but that is MinGW + Windows problem ). Wish I could know does linux gcc version has this kind of probem.

Comment: With C99 `long double` can be printed with "%Le", "%Lg" etc and I think under linux this works without problems. Your problem is probably not in the compiler itself (gcc) but in the support that your runtime library offers.

Comment: Yes, In Windows world double and long double is the same. However in MINGW long double is larger than double, however it can print only the long double of MS Windows, that is the double.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... apparently the combination "latest gcc + MinGW + Netbeans + Windows" does not provide a compliant C99 compiler.

The standard specifically documents those identifiers as being defined in the header `<inttypes.h>`

> 7.8  Format conversion of integer types <inttypes.h>
>   [...]
>   7.8.1
>   [...]
>         [#4] The fscanf macros for signed integers are:
>
> ```
>        SCNdN    SCNdLEASTN    SCNdFASTN     SCNdMAX    SCNdPTR
>        SCNiN    SCNiLEASTN    SCNiFASTN     SCNiMAX    SCNiPTR
>
>   [#5] The fscanf macros for unsigned integers are:
>
>        SCNoN    SCNoLEASTN    SCNoFASTN     SCNoMAX    SCNoPTR
>        SCNuN    SCNuLEASTN    SCNuFASTN     SCNuMAX    SCNuPTR
>        SCNxN    SCNxLEASTN    SCNxFASTN     SCNxMAX    SCNxPTR
> ```

Comment: yeah, I'm just learning c and reason why I'm not using Visual C++ is lack of c99 features ( VC++ is good for C++ ). Maybe I'll try NetBeans or Visual Studio with Intel C Compiler

Answer (score 0):

I see this is defined in `inttypes.h` in MinGW-w64 version 7.
You can get a build of GCC with this MinGW-w64 version from: http://winlibs.com