# C-int8_t wont work

Tags: c

I have issues executing the code mentioned below.I get an eror while using `int8_t` but not when using `int16_t`. The errors I get when using `int8_t` are:

> 12 19 [Error] expected ')' before 'SCNd8'
>       16 19 [Error] expected ')' before 'SCNd8'

Can anyone help me with this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int main()
{
int8_t N,D,quotient,remainder;
 D=0;
    printf("enter the Numerator between 0-255: \n");
    scanf("%hhd" SCNd8 ,&N);
    printf("enter the Denominator between 1-255: \n");

    do{
        scanf("%hhd"SCNd8 ,&D);
        if (D==0)
           {
               printf("denominator cant be 0 \n");
               printf("enter the Denominator between 1-255: \n");
           }
    }while(D==0);

        quotient=N/D;
        remainder=N%D;
printf("The quotient is %"PRId8"\n",quotient);
printf("The remainder is %"PRId8"\n",remainder);
```

Comment: `"%hhd" SCNd8` --> `"%" SCNd8`

Comment: Also `int8_t` : -128～127

Comment: Perhaps check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101335/does-gccwindows-mingw-defines-scnd8-scnu8-in-inttypes-h?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using

Comment: If you are using a C++11 compiler, then a space is required between string literals and macros.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%hhd" SCNd8 ,&N);
```

to

```
scanf("%" SCNd8 ,&N);
```

This is as SCNd8 is typically defined as

```
#define SCNd8 "hhd"
```

So, you don't need to add the `hhd` yourself

Comment: While correct, that's unlikely to be causing this specific error.